# Get grouped data from objects in C#

Tags: c#, grouping

I have a data:

```
data e1 = new data() { eventId = 1, eventName = "event1", hobbies = "hobbies1", note = "note1" };
data e2 = new data() { eventId = 1, eventName = "event1", hobbies = "hobbies2", note = "note2" };
data e3 = new data() { eventId = 2, eventName = "event2", hobbies = "hobbies3", note = "note3" };
data e4 = new data() { eventId = 2, eventName = "event2", hobbies = "hobbies4", note = "note4" };
```

I need this to be grouped to a `List<Event>` class based on eventId and eventName, and eventDetails should be grouped as per eventId and eventName as a  `List<EventDetails>` property containing 'hobbies' and 'note' values.

```
public class Event
{
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public List<EventDetails> eventDetails { get; set; }
}

//i want to get a List<Event> which group e1,e2 together and e3,e4 together
```

Can this be done? not sure from where I need to start. What is the best possible solution I can use?

Comment: you can use linq!

Comment: Do you have the list of data objects?

Comment: can you direct me to any example

Comment: yes i have data object coming form database in an sql datareader

Comment: Read up on EntityFramework, or any other SQL ORM.

Comment: Need to use ADO.net. Entity Framework is not an option here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ method to achieve this:

```
data e1 = new data() { eventId = 1, eventName = "event1", hobbies = "hobbies1", note = "note1" };
data e2 = new data() { eventId = 1, eventName = "event1", hobbies = "hobbies2", note = "note2" };
data e3 = new data() { eventId = 2, eventName = "event2", hobbies = "hobbies3", note = "note3" };
data e4 = new data() { eventId = 2, eventName = "event2", hobbies = "hobbies4", note = "note4" };

data[] arr = { e1, e2, e3, e4 };

List<Event> groupedList = arr.GroupBy(i => i.eventId)
    .Select(j => new Event()
    {
        eventId = j.First().eventId,
        eventName = j.First().eventName,
        eventDetail = j.Select(f => new EventDetails()
        {
            hobbies = f.hobbies,
            note = f.note
        }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have the List objects, you can try it like

```
List<data> dataObjects = ...
List<Event> eventsData = dataObjects.Select(p=> new Event(){ eventId = p.eventId, eventName = p.eventName, 
                                    eventdetail = dataObjects.Where(q=> q.eventId == p.eventId).Select(r=> new EventDetails(){ hobbies = r.hobbies, note = r.note }).ToList() }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Make sure you have a constructor in your Event class that initializes the List like

```
public class Event
{
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public List<EventDetails> eventdetail { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {
        eventdetail = new List<EventDetails>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me duplicate events .. but I get the point you are trying to make. Will give it a try. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: You can call `.Distinct` on it to remove the duplicates and glad it helped :)

Comment: That `.Distinct()` does not remove duplicate events. i think HSG wants to group e1,e2 together and also e3,e4

Comment: Yes S. Serp you are right . I want e1,e2 together and e3,e4 together.